# Hazelcast: should I override hashCode or equals to use in a map

Tags: equals, hashcode, hazelcast

This general question is mostly out of curiosity rather then a concern.

Should hashCode and equals for mapped entity be overridden to face basic Hazelcast features properly?
And is there a known concern we can be faced with if default behavior is not overridden?

Answer (score 1):

The following link lists common mistakes while using Hazelcast.
The very first point is :
**equals() and hashCode() methods for the objects stored in Hazelcast**

That might answer your question.

http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/multi_html/ch18.html